# Using createDocument( ...) with Alfresco Mobile SDK for Android, how to obtain a ContentFile from a file?

Tags: android, upload, alfresco

I am trying to upload a file inside a *repository* on **Alfresco**.

I am using the Alfresco Mobile SDK for **Android** that is well documented and easy to use.

The problem is that I didn't find how to create an object `ContentFile` from a file (the one that I want to upload), in order to use the method:

```
public Document createDocument(Folder folder, String nameFile,
Map<String,Serializable> properties, ContentFile contentFile)
```

(this method works great, I am able to create a file without content).

I am pretty sure it is not big deal but I am looking around and don'y manage to find what I need.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = Login.session.getServiceRegistry();
DocumentFolderService documentFolderService = 
    serviceRegistry.getDocumentFolderService();
Folder folder = (Folder) 
    documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(repository.getIdentifier());

Map<String,Serializable> properties = new HashMap<String,Serializable>();

// here I would like to take the content from the fileFrom:
ContentFile contentFile = null; 

// fileFrom is a File object:
String nameFile = fileFrom.getName(); 

documentFolderService.createDocument(folder, nameFile, properties, contentFile);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`ContentFileImpl`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/mobileSDK/Android/org/alfresco/mobile/android/api/model/impl/ContentFileImpl.html) class:

```
//...
String location = "..."; // wherever you have to point to
ContentFile contentFile = new ContentFileImpl(new File(location));
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was looking for ! It is working very good, I should have post a question before

Comment: Great to hear! Remember to accept the answer if it worked for you ;-)